# Positioning a Kivy Animation On Screen.

Tags: kivy

I've been playing with the code from [How to make a repetitive rotating animation in Kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321832/how-to-make-a-repetitive-rotating-animation-in-kivy). In the code below I'm using it to rotate an image of a 45RPM record. I'd like to change the position of the record from the center of the screen to spin in the upper right corner of the screen.

I've searched but can't find any information on how to re-position the image towards the upper right corner and/or information on how to ensure it keeps rotating properly once moved.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

....brad....

Image for code at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-T2cvsAoZ2vQ2hmaHM0SnlQVlU

```
# Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321832/how-to-make-a-repetitive-rotating-animation-in-kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_string('''                               
<Loading>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
    Image:
        source: '45rpm.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 200
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
''')

class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0

class RotationAnimation(App):
    def build(self):
        return Loading()

RotationAnimation().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for a clear question.

The problem is that you are using your `Loading` class as the main widget, it should instead be called `LoadingCircle` or `LoadingRecord` or something like that and used together with other widgets.

So, first of all, add another main widget (I'll add a `FloatLayout`). Then I'll tell the `Loading` where to go using `pos_hint` and set its size to whatever I want.

Here's the code:

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''                               
<Loading>:
    # Describe the record's position and size here
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 200
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
    Image:
        source: '45rpm.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.parent.size # So we don't have to change it every time, change the size above only
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
''')


class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle=360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle=360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0


class RotationAnimation(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()  # The new main widget
        f.add_widget(Loading())  # Add the loading record to it
        return f


RotationAnimation().run()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: End result]

Comment: That's really great and it should get me started. It also may help me down the line to work with multiple animated widgets. Would you know where I look to find out more information on how to work with the pos_hint property? I'm really interested in altering and learning more about the pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1} so I can more finely adjust  the position of the animation.

Comment: Well, yes and no. There is no definitive tutorial for kivy, unfortunately. However, the docs are pretty good. https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint That is a good starting point. Just google the things that interest you and you should hopefully find some docs. Other than that, if you have the time and motivation, just look through some kivy examples or the code of others. By the way, consider accepting the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify this code even further (for those reading it at a later date) and to answer my question in the comments of Edvardas's answer, I now understand how the pos_hint property can be altered to adjust the position of the animation.

In Edvardas's answer he used pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1} to declare the position of the 45RPM record animation. It placed the animation in the fullest upper right position on the screen without the animation exceeding the boundaries of the Kivy GUI. This pos_hint of 'top': 1, 'right': 1 moved the animation from lower left hand corner default position to the upper right hand corner of the GUI without exceeding the limits of the window.

In my code below I use pos_hint: {'top': .7, 'right': 1.1}. These numbers place the top of the animation 70% up the screen and the right had side of the animation off the screen. So for me I think of top as "up the screen from the bottom" and right as "across the screen from the left".

Bottom line knowing this I can now accurately place my animation to any point on the screen. Very useful information. My thanks again.

My output looks as follows and I've place the working code below;

[image]

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''                               
<Loading>:
    # Describe the record's position and size here
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 200
    pos_hint: {'top': .7, 'right': 1.1}
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
    Image:
        source: '45rpm.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.parent.size # So we don't have to change it every time, change the size above only
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
''')

class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle=360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle=360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0

class RotationAnimation(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()  # The new main widget
        f.add_widget(Loading())  # Add the loading record to it
        return f

RotationAnimation().run()
```