# Trying to add an animation on speedometer in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to make the needle on my speedometer to move from left to right. Is there a function for it to make the animation? A simple function or help will do.

[image: kivy screen]

.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App

class SpeedWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

KV = """

WindowManager:
    SpeedWindow:

<SpeedWindow>:

    Image:
        source: 'cadran.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 400
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

    Image:
        source: 'needle.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 300
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

"""



class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return  Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: You can use `Rotate` and `Animation`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321832/how-to-make-a-repetitive-rotating-animation-in-kivy) similar application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Rotate` and `Animation`, you can animate the needle rotation like:

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App

class SpeedWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

KV = """

WindowManager:
    SpeedWindow:

<SpeedWindow>:
    angle: 90    # angle for needle
    name: 'speedometer'    # every Screen needs a name

    Image:
        source: 'cadran.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 400
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

    Image:
        source: 'needle.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 300
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}   
        # apply rotation matrix to this Image                                                                                                                                            
        canvas.before:                                                                                                                                             
            PushMatrix                                                                                                                                             
            Rotate:                                                                                                                                                
                angle: root.angle                                                                                                                                  
                axis: (0, 0, 1)                                                                                                                                    
                origin: (self.center_x, self.center_y - self.norm_image_size[1]/2, 0)                                                                                                                              
        canvas.after:                                                                                                                                              
            PopMatrix                           

"""



class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.animate_needle, 2.0)  # start the animation in 2 seconds
        return  Builder.load_string(KV)

    def animate_needle(self, dt):
        # animate the needle from +90 to -90 and then back to +90
        self.anim = Animation(angle=-90.0) + Animation(angle=90)
        self.anim.repeat = True    # repeat forever
        speedometer = self.root.get_screen('speedometer')
        self.anim.start(speedometer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: thank you ! May i know what is the PushMatrix and PopMatrix for?

Comment: when i run the code, i got an error `TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType kivy` and it pointed at the `angle:root.angle`

Comment: Did you include the `angle: 90` in the `<SpeedWindow>` section?

Comment: There is a `modelview_mat` matrix that is applied to the `Canvas` graphics before it is displayed. The `PushMatrix` pushes the current matrix onto a stack, then the `Rotate` creates a new matrix that does our desired rotation. Then the `PopMatrix` pops the matrix stack to restore the previously saved matrix. Using `canvas.before` sets up the rotation before the `needle.png` `Image` is displayed, and the `canvas.after` restores the old matrix after the needle is displayed.

Comment: The code that I posted works. There must be something else affecting it.

Comment: okay i got it running...but how to do i make it go continuously from left to right and back to left

Comment: I have modified my answer to show what you want. To make sequential `Animations` simply use the `+`  operator. If you want them to repeat, just set `repeat` to `True`. To stop the `Animation`, use `self.anim.stop(speedometer)`.