# 2d graphics in Python Kivy, advice is needed

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I still have been studying world of Kivy and I have encountered with question. I am designing an interface. it has to have an appearance of analog device with arrow and curved scale like old voltmeters were. Just to display a data on the screen. I've tried to use canvas, but I stacked with resizing of window properties. Built canvas object was either connected to specific size in px, or changed location on the screen in wrong way. So, I am curious, maybe here are some others ways to embed objects which were built in another 2d graphics library, I am aware of existence of 3d module vpython and turtle. Maybe we have some more?
Can anybody give me a hint? I would be very grateful

kivy, canvas
[view of my prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rix3T.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Image` widgets combined with `Button Behavior` or `ToggleButton Behavior` to make buttons that look like almost any kind of button that you like. And you can make a curved scale as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081724/trying-to-add-an-animation-on-speedometer-in-kivy/59097020#59097020).